# When does Apache re-read the updates to .htaccess files?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a hosted server.

When I update .htaccess, are the updated rules *immediately* in effect?

I understand that hosters can do what they want, and it's impossible to know without knowing the particular policy of this particular hoster. But in the normal case, if I update .htaccess, does Apache re-read it immediately?  Or is there something I can do to tell Apache to re-read it?

or what?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `.htaccess` is loaded up on each request, even if it's in internal one (using mod_modrewrite)

Take and look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html and especially the 'When (not) to use' section

Comment: beat me by 7 seconds, upvote for you

Comment: Ha, I even reloaded to make sure there wasn't one already posted

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I googled for `mod_rewrite .htaccess update` but the signal-to-noise ratio was really really  low.

Comment: Yeah, information overload when searching Google. I always start with the apache docs first